# Spring Boot Security Authentication from third API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I build a web app using spring boot + thymeleaf,
but this project is client (not backend / not using database), i'm consuming third API (login, store data,load data,update data, delete data),
i have a problem when implementation spring boot security, username and password authentication with third API,
this endpoint for login auth (third API)

```
http://kuala/app/directory/user/login?j_username=admin&j_password=admin
```

success response

```
{
"isAdmin": "true",
"username": "admin"}
```

failed response

```
{
"error": {
    "date": "Fri Jan 24 10:29:26 ICT 2020",
    "code": "401",
    "message": ""
}}
```

this sample SecurityConfig

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.
            authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
}}
```

any one help me,
thanks in advance

best regard

Khafidz

Comment: im using AuthenticationProvider

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create your own `AuthenticationManager` bean, and delegate the authenticate call to the 3rd party (using a RestTemplate, for example):

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
         // Call your 3rd party API and return an Authentication object based
         // on its response
         ResponseEntity loginResponse = restTemplate.exchange(...);

         if(loginResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
             // create a valid Authentication object with roles, etc
         }
         else {
             // throw an exception such as BadCredentialsException
         }
    }
}
```